# Sympy "not all arguments converted during string formatting" when using zeros((n,n))

Tags: python, sympy

I am running sympy on an external computer, but when I do the simple command

```
M=sympy.zeros((2,2))
```

I get the error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    M=sp.zeros((2,2))
  File "/apps/brussel/magnycours/software/sympy/0.7.6-intel-2015a-Python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/matrices/dense.py", line 1229, in zeros
    return cls.zeros(r, c)
  File "/apps/brussel/magnycours/software/sympy/0.7.6-intel-2015a-Python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/matrices/dense.py", line 513, in zeros
    r = as_int(r)
  File "/apps/brussel/magnycours/software/sympy/0.7.6-intel-2015a-Python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/compatibility.py", line 389, in as_int
    raise ValueError('%s is not an integer' % n)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

However, when I run it on my own computer, there is no problem. How can I fix this?

The version on my computer is 0.7.1.rc1, while the one on the cluster is 0.7.6. Should I ask them to install the (older?) version or is there an easier fix??

Comment: I bet the `sympy.zeros` function has different arguments in the version on the cluster. I'd look at API docs for `0.7.6` to see what it's supposed to take.

Comment: Your actual error, is the `ValueError` shown in the stack trace. During construction of its error message the `TypeError` is raised. Presumably because n is a tuple but was expected to be an integer.

Comment: Thanks, that was a very simple solution, now it works without issues. The syntax is indeed different between the two versions (which imo is quite retarded, the new version should at least be able to recognize and notify when one is trying an old syntax instead of throwing cryptic error messages).

Comment: @JonathanLindgren The old API was deprecated since and 0.7.2 and removed in 0.7.6. You should update the package frequently or see the release notes of previous releases. See this https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/6480

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 2x2 matrix with zeros, try this:

```
In [6]: zeros(2,2)
Out[6]: 
Matrix([
[0, 0],
[0, 0]])
```

or

```
In [7]: zeros(2)
Out[7]: 
Matrix([
[0, 0],
[0, 0]])
```